# I want to submit the user id and product id when clicking on a href that link to page containing php code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this is the store.php page

```
<a href=\"order.php?id=".$row[prod_id]."\">Order</a>
```

And the order.php contains

```
<?php

$email = "mis@es-tg.com";
#add your code here now or later to connect to the MySQL database.
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$con = mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con); 

$charset = mysql_client_encoding($con);

mysql_select_db("scientology", $con);
$sql = "Insert into requested_product values (stdid,prod_id) where prod_id=".$_GET['prod_id']  , stdid=".$_GET['stdid'];
$result = mysql_query ("$sql");
if(!($result))
   echo "<BR><font color=red>Thank you for ordering</font>";
echo $sql;
header("Location: store.php");
?>
```

By this page I am trying to insert the product id and the if of the user who is logged in into requested_produt table which is like this
[image: requested_product]

Comment: <a href=\"order.php?id=".$row[prod_id]."\">Order</a> replace with <a href=\"order.php?iprod_id=".$row[prod_id]."&".$stdid=".$row['stdid']."\">Order</a>

Comment: Check insert query syntax!! It is like `INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);` We don't use `WHERE`clause in insert query

Comment: You NEED Basic Tutorials. Full Of Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0):

In store.php, you are sending `id` but you are reading `$_GET['prod_id']` in order.php. Replace `$_GET['prod_id']` with `$_GET['id']`.